# How to resolve Mysql error 13 for loading data infile

Tags: python, mysql, load-data-infile

I have seen several question regarding this error, and have tried all the suggested solutions with no success.

I am running a python script to parse xml into csv file and then load it to MySQL database. Every other step goes well, get the connection successfully. but the loading of data fails with the following error.

```
[Extracted .xml. Time:4.34389615059]
- Starting write .csv
[Written CSV files. Cost:0.208467006683]
[Finishing processing one .zip package! Time consuming:16.2964661121]
[Process 6000 is finished. Cost Time:8763.27494121]
[Finished all xml4 files]
== Parseing Cost:9802.73910308 ==
- Starting load CSV files.
Connected successfully!()
***** PUBLICATION *****
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PublicationsParser.py", line 931, in <module>
po.loadCSV()
File "PublicationsParser.py", line 691, in loadCSV
""".format(filePath=self.csvPath_publication.replace('\\','/')))
File "/home/phesto/Downloads/Documents/USPTO/MySQLProcessor.py", line 39, in load
self._cursor.execute(sql)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-            i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 202, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-  i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (13, "Can't get stat of     '/home/phesto/Downloads/Documents/USPTO/CSV_P/publications.csv' (Errcode: 13)")
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2
```

And here is the file permission of the folder, same for all the content of this folder

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root phesto    4096 Apr 25 02:54 CSV_P
```

I have tried both LOCAL INFILE and INFILE without local.

I have also added this path to apparmour mysqld
   /home/phesto/Downloads/Documents/USPTO/* rw,

And the Python codes are here http://abel.lis.illinois.edu/upet/download.php

I need your expert help.

Comment: When not using `LOCAL`, does the file exist on the server somewhere that the mysqld process can access it (residing in a user's download directory, I suspect not)?  When using `LOCAL`, does the file exist somewhere that the Python process can access it; and are both server and client enabled for `LOAD DATA LOCAL` - see [Security Issues with `LOAD DATA LOCAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data-local.html)?

Comment: The files are residing in the path above, users document, i have given permission to root, I have tried to have the files in /tmp with same results. A Regarding security issues I have added ` local-infile=1` in `[mysql]` and `[mysqld]` entries in my.cnf of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

All the parent/upper folders also have to be readable to MySQL.

Comment: I have created a folder in root with root rights and copied my scripts and folder structure there. I run the Publications.py and after the process, got same results. Error 13 can't get stat of...